# Error loading a restas module without slime, on the command line

Tags: common-lisp, slime, quicklisp

I am new to common lisp and want to build a web with RESTAS.
I write a file called api.lisp, it looks like this:

```
(ql:quickload :restas)
(restas:define-module xxx ) ......
```

I write some routes, and it works well in Emacs+Slime.
But when i try to load the file in command line, it doesn't work .

```
Bash>> lx86cl64 -l ~/Git/proj53/src/api/api.lisp


To load "restas":
  Load 1 ASDF system:
    restas
; Loading "restas"
.
> Error: There is no package named "SWANK" .
> While executing: CCL::%FASL-NVPACKAGE, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Retry finding package with name "SWANK".
> Type :? for other options.
1 >
```

Why i got this error?

Comment: That looks like a restas problem. My guess: the restas version was compiled while Swank (a part of SLIME) was loaded. For example when you compiled/loaded it with SLIME. Now restas assumes in the compiled code that there is a package SWANK. If you start it from outside SLIME, the SWANK package is not there. You may try to recompile the whole of restas without SLIME being used and also file a bug report to the restas developer.